# Manipulating blobs in C++

Tags: c++, blob

I will be reading and writing large chucks of a large binary file.

Is there a class in standard C++ or upcoming standard C++ or upcoming standard C++ + boost, that will make my task easier?

If not would it be possible to use the string class for this? What would be the dangers of doing so?

PS: A few observations that will clarify things. I expect that the blobs will be passed around a lot, so a container that is reference counted and CoW would probably be preferable.

Also my resistance to using a string class is twofold: these are blobs, not strings, "unprintable characters" and in particular nulls may cause difficulties when they appear.

Comment: There is - `unsigned char *`. What else you need from a blob?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner That is not true of `std::string`; it's only true if you call `c_str()` and explicitly treat it as a C-style string.

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek I sit corrected, thanks :)

Comment: You meant `void*` of course ;-)

Comment: What manipulation will you be doing? A `std::vector<unsigned char>` would probably be fine.

Comment: Voted to close because the question is too vague. How much data are we talking about? What kinds of operations do you want to perform? Is your focus on high performance or simple code or something else? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a blob of binary data you can store this easily and efficiently in a `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

You can increase performance if you know (or can guess) the size of the blobs by calling [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve).

And finally, if you use streams you can easily read into a vector using [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you want to do, a memory mapped file, [such as the one from boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html#mapped_file), is probably a good starting point. For in-memory modification, use an std::vector, as others have suggested.

Don't bother with CoW - it's mostly frowned upon in the C++ world, with the possible exception of everything in Qt.